# HTML form doesn't submit input data into URL

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, search, get

I have an HTML form with the following code:

```
<form action="search/" method="get">
    <input type="search" value="search for..." id="search" />
</form>
```

When I hit the ENTER key, it submits to the specified page in the action attribute, BUT it doesn't ADD the input value to the URL.

I would like someone searching for "politician" keyword GOING to something like "kereso/politician"

I'm using HTACCESS to manage SEO friendly URLs with the following code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^haromszekirmdsz.ro
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.haromszekirmdsz.ro/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Comment: Your input doesn't have a name attribute.

Answer (score 9):

You are not giving the name attribute in the input field

> ```
> <input name="url" .......... />
> ```

Comment: @user1185551 - accept if it resolves your problem, so that other can also find the solution

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a name attribute to the input field.

```
<input type="search" value="search for..." name="search" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget adding `name`:

```
<form action="search/" method="get">
  <input name="search" type="text" value="search for..." id="search" />
</form>
```